# Assign property values of an object in a CodeObjectCreateExpression

Tags: c#, .net-core, codedom

I need to create an object like this (see below) using CodeDOM.

```
internal static readonly Dynamic class1 = new Dynamic
{
    VendorId = "VTS",
    Test = 10.33f

};
```

What I did try has to create a constructor (see below) in the class `Dynamic`(which was created using CodeDOM) which takes all the needed values to set as parameters.Sadly, after getting it all right the code that uses the `Dynamic` class gave an error which was that it cannot use a constructor with parameters (because it is a data structure for `ML.NET`)

```
CodeConstructor constructor = new CodeConstructor();

constructor.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;

constructor.Parameters.Add(new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(typeof(float), "test"));

CodeFieldReferenceExpression reference =
    new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
        new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), "test");

constructor.Statements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(reference, 
    new CodeArgumentReferenceExpression("test")));

targetClass.Members.Add(constructor);
```

How would I assign values to the properties without the need of parameters in the constructor using CodeDOM?

Comment: That's an object initializer, not a constructor call. It's equivalent to having a `static` constructor perform `class1 = new Dynamic(); class1.VendorId = "VTS"; class1.Test = 10.33f`. Parameters are unnecessary because the calling code can't possibly use them -- there's no opportunity to parameterize the static initializer. Exactly what code should be generated depends on your context, but generating a call to the default constructor and then code to set the properties would be a start. Alternatively, set the properties directly in the constructor (but then the values can't vary).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm going to try and set the properties directly in the constructor.
The values are just for running tests and if the user really needs to change them I could just add functions that regenerate the class with new values using CodeDOM. Thank you very much for the idea. I'll give it a shot and see if it will work with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @JeroenMostert in comments I was able to find a solution to my problem that could be use as a data structure for ML.NET :

```
 CodeConstructor constructor = new CodeConstructor
        {
            Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public
        };


    foreach (var item in features)
        {
            CodeFieldReferenceExpression reference =
            new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
                new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), item.Id);

            constructor.Statements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(reference, new CodePrimitiveExpression(item.TestCase)));
        }

        targetClass.Members.Add(constructor);
```